# Unable to open encrypted SqLite database

Tags: c#, sqlite, encryption

I encrypt my database with this :

```
fDatabaseOptions = new SQLiteConnectionString(fConfiguration.DatabasePath, true, key: fConfiguration.DatabaseEncryptionKey);
fConnection = new SQLiteConnection(fDatabaseOptions);
```

I am now trying to view the database via 3rd party software. When I try to open the Db, I get variations of "not a database file" errors. When I do this without encryption, the db opens fine.

I've tried using several different tools to open the database, but always get the same problem.
Im using two dependencies for this :

- sqlite-net-pc (1.7.335)
- sqlite-net-sqlcipher (1.7.335)

Some of the tools that I've tried :

- DataDevelop
- SqLite Maestro
- SqLiteAdmin
- SQLiteStudio

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the first line of code. Run to it. Go to the `Immediate Window` and type in `?fConfiguration.DatabasePath`. What **exactly** is shown?

Comment: .\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\myDb.str

Comment: Does it work if you use a fully qualified path (i.e. starts with C:\ rather than .)?

Comment: @mjwills, no, it still has the same problem. As mentioned in the question, this does work when there is no password specified, so the problem is not related to the path.

Comment: Yes, I tried that explicitly. Yes, there is a reason why I'm using str, and I've used other extensions as well, with the same result.